# How to check if dataframe row name matches column name

Tags: python, pandas

I want to loop through a dataframe, checking to see if the row name matches the column name. If they match, I want to set the value for the intersection to zero. I've tried several options but none of them works. Here is pseudocode that shows what I want to do:

```
for row in dataframe:
    if row_name == column_name:
        dataframe[rowname][columnname] = 0
```

This is what the data looks like:

```
        NAME1    NAME2    NAME3
NAME1    1       .9         .2
NAME2    .6      1          .7
NAME3    .5      .8         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the intersection of your index and columns. Then iterate the intersection and use `pd.DataFrame.loc` to set values.

```
intersection = df.index & df.columns

for item in intersection:
    df.loc[item, item] = 0

print(df)

       NAME1  NAME2  NAME3
NAME1    0.0    0.9    0.2
NAME2    0.6    0.0    0.7
NAME3    0.5    0.8    0.0
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I will accept as soon as I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

More convoluted method than @jpp's, you could [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) the df so the column names form the second level of the index :

```
In[296]:
stack = df.stack()
stack

Out[296]: 
NAME1  NAME1    1.0
       NAME2    0.9
       NAME3    0.2
NAME2  NAME1    0.6
       NAME2    1.0
       NAME3    0.7
NAME3  NAME1    0.5
       NAME2    0.8
       NAME3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Then we can mask the stacked df and set to `0` where the index level values match:

```
In[297]:
stack.loc[stack.index.get_level_values(0) == stack.index.get_level_values(1)] = 0
stack

Out[297]: 
NAME1  NAME1    0.0
       NAME2    0.9
       NAME3    0.2
NAME2  NAME1    0.6
       NAME2    0.0
       NAME3    0.7
NAME3  NAME1    0.5
       NAME2    0.8
       NAME3    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Then we call [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) to revert back to our original df:

```
In[298]:
stack.unstack()

Out[298]: 
       NAME1  NAME2  NAME3
NAME1    0.0    0.9    0.2
NAME2    0.6    0.0    0.7
NAME3    0.5    0.8    0.0
```

This has more of a performance hit on a small df as you're creating temporary df's from the calls to `stack` and `unstack` but if you have large overlaps of index and column values then it avoids the `looping`

Comment: Thanks... I'll check it out.